# use Jquery - in a nested list of parent/child check boxes - check or uncheck parent based on child state

Tags: jquery, recursion, checkbox, nested-lists

If you check a child in the list, all the parents should become checked.

If you un-check a child in the list and there are other children that ARE checked the parent should remain checked.

finaly, if you un-check all children in the list the parent should become un-checked as well

http://jsfiddle.net/snEfq/14/

```
<li data-id="1">
    <input class="cat_check" data-pid="0" type="checkbox" value="1" id="1" checked/>Exterior Signs
        <ul class="category_select_list">
            <li data-id="15">
                <input class="cat_check" data-pid="1" type="checkbox" value="15" id="15" checked/>Monument
            </li>
            <li data-id="17">
                <input class="cat_check" data-pid="1" type="checkbox" value="17" id="17" checked/>Channel Letters
                <ul class="category_select_list">
                    <li data-id="28">
                        <input class="cat_check" data-pid="17" type="checkbox" value="28" id="28" checked/>Neon Channel Letter
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-id="16">
                <input class="cat_check" data-pid="1" type="checkbox" value="16" id="16" checked/>Banners
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

each box has an id, and data-pid attribute

data-pid is its parent with 0=top level

Neon Channel Letters has a pid of 17 - child

and channel letters has a pid of 1 - parent to neon, child of exterior

and exterior signs has a pid of 0 - top level parent

```
 $('.cat_check').click(function () {
    tid = $(this).attr('value');
    state = $(this).prop('checked');
    pid = $(this).data('pid');
    check_parent(pid, state);
    cc(tid, state);

    function cc(tid, state) {
        $(':input').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('pid') == tid) {
                $(this).prop('checked', state);
                cc($(this).attr('value'), state)
            }

        });
    }
});
```

> //This function works unless you are un-checking a child and there are children still checked. Then it un-checks the parent.

```
function check_parent(pid, state){
    if (pid != 0){
        $('#'+pid).prop('checked', state);
        this_pid = $('#'+pid).data('pid');
        check_parent(this_pid, state);
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions and help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVF5N/1/). The code needs to be refactored but functionality should be according to your needs.

```
function checkSiblings(target) {
    var siblingsChecked = 0;
    target.parent('li').siblings('li').children('input').each(function(i, el){
        if ($(el).is(':checked')) {
            siblingsChecked++;
        }
    });

    if (siblingsChecked === 0) {
        var possibleParent = target.parent('li').parents('li').eq(0).children('input');
        if (possibleParent.length) {
            //console.log('we have a parent');
            possibleParent.prop('checked', false);
        }
        else {
            //console.log('nothing');
        }
    }
}

$('.cat_check').on('click', function (ev) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parents('li').each(function(i, el){
            $(el).children('input').prop('checked', true);
        });
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent('li').find('input').prop('checked', false);
        checkSiblings($(this));
    }
});
```

UPDATED CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/gZEry/

```
function checkSiblings(target) {
    var siblingsChecked = 0;
    target.parent('li').siblings('li').children('input').each(function(i, el){
        if ($(el).is(':checked')) {
            siblingsChecked++;
        }
    });

    if (siblingsChecked === 0) {
        var possibleParent = target.parent('li').parents('li').eq(0).children('input');
        if (possibleParent.length) {
            //console.log('we have a parent');
            possibleParent.prop('checked', false);
        }
        else {
            //console.log('nothing');
        }
    }
}

$('.cat_check').on('click', function (ev) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // check all children
        $(this).parent('li').each(function(i, el){
            $(el).find('input').prop('checked', true);
        });
        // check inputs on the way up
        $(this).parents('li').each(function(i, el){
            $(el).children('input').prop('checked', true);
        });
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent('li').find('input').prop('checked', false);
        checkSiblings($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: This is really close... I am trying to figure out how to adjust your code to where when you re-check a check box it goes through and checks all the children... right now it does not.